# Intervals are connected and the only connected sets in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

As the topic, prove that Intervals are connected and only connected  in $\mathbb{R}$. I know what is the definition of connected set. But not sure how to prove that.

Comment: Maybe some of the discussion here is helpful? [Set $A$ interval in $\mathbb{R}\implies$ connected](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113007/set-a-interval-in-mathbbr-implies-connected)

Comment: In Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin, a proof for the same is given.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$HINTS: Suppose that $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ is not an interval; then there are points $a,b\in A$ and $x\in\Bbb R\setminus A$ such that $a<x<b$. Use the sets $A\cap(\leftarrow,x)$ and $A\cap(x,\to)$ to show that $A$ is not connected.

The other direction is a bit harder. Suppose that $A$ is not connected. Then there is an open set $U$ in $\Bbb R$ such that $A\cap U\ne\varnothing\ne A\setminus U$ and $A\cap U=
A\cap\cl U$; why? Fix $a\in A\cap U$ and $b\in A\setminus U$ and show that $[a,b]\nsubseteq A$, so that $A$ cannot be an interval.

Comment: Actually is it true that if two sets are disjoint, no matter it is open or not it is disconnected. As by the definition, it seems to requires that 2 sets are open

Comment: @Mathematics: $[0,1)$ and $[1,2]$ are disjoint, but their union is $[0,2]$, which is connected. It is important that $A\cap U$ and $A\setminus U$ are both relatively open subsets of $A$.

Comment: $A\cup U\ne\emptyset\ne A\setminus U\implies A\cup U \ne A\setminus U$?I am a little bit confused with the notation

Comment: @Mathematics: No, it doesn’t. But it’s true that $A\cup U\ne A\setminus U$, simply because $U\ne\varnothing$. I think that you’re making this more complicated than it really is; all I’m saying is that if $A$ is not connected, there must be an open $U$ in $\Bbb R$ such that $A\cap U$ and $A\setminus\cl U$ are non-empty relatively open subsets of $A$ whose union is $A$ $-$ in other words, a disconnection of $A$.

Comment: This proof doesn't seem to cover singleton sets. Am I missing something? Singleton sets are connected sets in $\mathbb{R}$, no?

Comment: @William: Yes, singletons in any topological space are connected.  And in $\Bbb R$ they are also intervals: $\{x\}=[x,x]$. The argument is complete, once the details are filled in: the first part shows that every connected subset of $\Bbb R$ is an interval, and the second part shows that every interval in $\Bbb R$ is connected.

Answer (score 0):

For one way, to prove every connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is interval, Brian's method works.

For the converse, there is an even simpler way:
Given an interval in $\mathbb{R}$, we can prove that it is path-connected.   Given two points in an interval, we can define the path as the line between them.

Path-connectivity implies connectivity.