# logarithmic derivative

Tags: real-analysis

It seems that when the logarithmic derivative of a function exists, the function itself cannot be zero. But I failed to  construct a convincent proof. Is this true?

$\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ is bounded implies $f(x)$ cannot have zero as a limiting value.

Is this true?

Comment: For $f'(x)/f(x)$ to even make sense, you need $f(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: Also, for $\ln f(x)$ to even make sense, you need $f(x)\ne 0$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I think you meant $f(x)>0$.

Comment: Thanks, I was not precise enough.  Of course f(x)≠0. But can f(x)  have zero as a limiting value?

Comment: I think this is kind of 0/0 limit...

Comment: @julien, I think Hagen's comment is fine. "For $X$, you need $Y$" means $\lnot Y\implies\lnot X$, not $Y\implies X$. For example, "for the matrix $A$ to be invertible, you need it to be square".

Comment: @RahulNarain Sure... I did not say it was not fine.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f:x\to \frac{1}{x}$ on $[1,+\infty)$, then we have
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=-\frac{1}{x},$$
so $\displaystyle\frac{f'}{f}$ is bounded on $[1,+\infty)$ Nevertheless $\displaystyle \lim_{+\infty}f=0.$

Comment: The statement is true at finite points.

Comment: Okay, thanks +1

Answer (score 3):

True when $x$ approaches a finite $x_0$, not when $x$ approaches $\pm \infty$, as explained below.

Assume $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.

Then the function
$$
g(x):=\ln|f(x)|
$$
is defined and differentiable on the open set
$$
U=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\;;\; f(x)\neq 0\}.
$$
Its derivative is
$$
g'(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\qquad \forall\;x\in U.
$$

Write $U=\bigcup_{n\geq 1}(a_n,b_n)$ as a countable disjoint union of open intervals. See [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318299/any-open-subset-of-bbb-r-is-a-countable-union-of-disjoint-open-intervals-co) to see why this is possible.

Consider for instance a finite point $x_0=a_n$.

Note that $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0^+}\ln |f(x)|=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0^+}g(x)=-\infty$.

Now if $g'=(\ln |f|)'$ was bounded by, say, $M$ on $(x_0,x_0+\delta]$, the mean value theorem, and then the triangular inequality, would yield
$$
|g(x)-g(x_0+\delta)|\leq M \delta\quad \Rightarrow\quad |g(x)|\leq |g(x_0+\delta)|+M\delta
$$
for all $x\in(x_0,x_0+\delta]$.

Contradiction.

So the logarithmic derivative is unbounded when it approaches every finite boundary point of $U$.

Now regarding the behavior at $\pm\infty$, you can easily find examples where $f'/f$ is bounded while $f$ tends to $0$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the $\Rightarrow$ properly. I get how the left-hand side is true but I'm not sure I understand the implication. Could you please add some more details?

Comment: @xavierm02 Sorry but what lhs are you talking about? And what implication?

Comment: I'm talking about the only place you wrote $a\Rightarrow b$ and the thing I call the left-hand side is the $a$.

Comment: @xavierm02 Ah, ok. This is the triangular inequality: $|g(x)|=|g(x)-g(y)+g(y)|\leq |g(x)-g(y)|+|g(y)|$.

Comment: Oh right >_< With your formulation I thought the mean value theorem gave the implication too whereas it only gives the left-hand side. Idk how I missed something that obvious >_<. Thanks :)

Comment: You write $U=\bigcup_{n\geq 1}(a_n,b_n)$ which means you assume there are countably many zeroes at most. It must come from the fact $f$ is differentiable but I can't see how... Does it?

Comment: @xavierm02  No, I use the fact that every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is the disjoint union of countably many open intervals.

Comment: @xavierm02 See this thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318299/any-open-subset-of-bbb-r-is-a-countable-union-of-disjoint-open-intervals-co

Comment: Coming to this topic after a long delay! Thanks you for the many answers and coments.