# the $\sigma$ algeba generated by the class of open intervals with rational end points coincide with the borel $\sigma$ algebra on the real line.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Show that the $\sigma$ algeba generated by the class of open intervals with rational end points coincide with the borel $\sigma$ algebra on the real line.

I tried to solve the question but I cannot do proper solution, thus i cannot write here. please show me this question. thank you.

Comment: Do you mean rational END points? You originally said in the title and your text "rational and points"

Comment: yes sorry for typo. i editted it. @user2566092

Comment: Are you aware of [this theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318299/any-open-subset-of-bbb-r-is-a-countable-union-of-disjoint-open-intervals-co)?

Comment: The linked duplicate asked a more open ended question, but its answer includes the answer to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:  Clearly the $\sigma$ algebra generated by open intervals with rational end points is contained in the Borel $\sigma$ algebra. So now you only need to show one thing:

- Any open interval can be written as a countable union of rational end point open intervals

Then you can show that any Borel $\sigma$ algebra set can be obtained through $\sigma$ algebra operations on the collection of rational endpoint open sets.