# Show that every open set in ℝ can be written as a countable union of open intervals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

This is what I have so far.

Let U ⊆ ℝ where U is open. By a theorem we have that all real numbers are uncountable and that rational numbers are dense in ℝ.

Comment: All real numbers are countable???

Comment: Real numbers are uncountable. Also, there are plenty of answers online, for example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318299/any-open-subset-of-bbb-r-is-a-at-most-countable-union-of-disjoint-open-interv)

Answer (score 3):

U=$\cup_{A}(ri,rj)$ where A is the set of rational tuples, so that (ri,rj) is a subset of U.
Obviously this is a subset of U. 
Now you habe to show, that it contains U: take any element of U: u, than because u is open, there is an open ball B with u in B. This ball can be arbitraily made smaller, so that it has rational borders. So u is in an open interval with rational borders, therefore in the Union.
The Union is countable, because the Rationals and therfore $\mathbb{Q}^{2}$ are.

Comment: Wait, why do you consider tuples? This was for $\mathbb{R}$ and not $\mathbb{R}^2$? Or are you referring to end points?