# Semiring measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Form the measure space $(\mathbb R,\Lambda,\lambda)$, where $\Lambda$ are the Lebesgue measurable sets and $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$.

> Show that, if $S\in \Lambda$ then
>
> $\lambda(S) = \inf\{\lambda(O): O\supseteq S, O \text{ open}\} = \sup\{\lambda(K): K\subseteq S, K \text{ compact}\}$

Answer (score 1):

This is called the **outer** and **inner regularities** of $\lambda$.

Observe that ($S \in \Lambda$)

> $$\lambda(S) = \inf\left\{\sum_{j=0}^\infty (b_j - a_j) \mid S \subseteq \bigcup_{j=0}^\infty \left]a_j,b_j\right[ \right\}$$

(This should not be hard to show, but depends on your definition of $\lambda$) Then outer regularity follows from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318299/any-open-subset-of-bbb-r-is-a-at-most-countable-union-of-disjoint-open-interv).

For inner regularity, without loss of generality let $S$ be bounded. (Otherwise, replace $S$ with a sequence of $S \cap [j,j+1]$)

By outer regularity, for $\epsilon > 0$ there exists open $U$ with $$U \supseteq S^- \setminus S, \qquad \lambda(U) \leq \lambda(S^- \setminus S) +\epsilon$$
Then $V = S^- \setminus U$ is compact and $V \subseteq S$, so
$$\begin{align*}
\lambda(V) &= \lambda(S) - \lambda(S \setminus U)\\
&=\lambda(S) - \lambda(U) + \lambda(U \setminus S) \\
&\geq \lambda(S) - \lambda(U) + (S^- \setminus S) \\
&\geq \lambda(S) +\epsilon
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I got interested with this question although its on another person's question.