# Any open subset of $S^1$ is an uniquely countable union of disjoint open intervals

Tags: general-topology

Expanding from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318299/any-open-subset-of-bbb-r-is-a-at-most-countable-union-of-disjoint-open-interv) question about $\mathbb{R}$ i want to know if this is also possible for $S^1$. Through the stereographic projection we have a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to $S^1\setminus\{p\}$, but i can't quiet finish the proof.

Comment: What do you mean be an open interval in $S^1$? Do you mean the image of an interval (in $\mathbb{R}$) under the map $t\mapsto e^{i t}$?

Comment: @Hayden, yes, alternatively because i mentioned it in the question the image of an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ of the inverse of the stereographic projection

Comment: Yes, but personally I don't find that to be a satisfying definition of 'interval' in $S^1$; it misses a lot of things that seem like 'intervals', and with that definition not every open subset of $S^1$ can be written as a countable union of disjoint 'open intervals' (take $S^1$ to be your open set; certainly isn't the countable union of disjoint preimages of open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ under any stereographic projections).  That said, any open *proper* subset of $S^1$ will be the preimage of a countable union of open interval of $\mathbb{R}$ under *some* stereographic projection.