# Borel algebra: countable unions of open sets only?

Tags: measure-theory

A quick question about the definition of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.
It was defined to me as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra generated by all open intervals.

What exactly does *generated by* refer to in rigorous terms?

I know an uncountable union of open sets is open, so it ought to be a Borel set, but does this follow from the definition (i.e. what is encompassed by *generated by*), or must some work be done to show that an uncountable union of open sets is a Borel set?

Comment: In rigorous terms, it means that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra equals the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras containing the open intervals. Note that it also contains every open subset of $\mathbb R$ since an open set can be expressed as a **countable** (even pairwise disjoint, but that's not needed here) union of open intervals. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318299/any-open-subset-of-bbb-r-is-a-at-most-countable-union-of-disjoint-open-interv), for example.

Comment: Alright. In that case I think some work must be done.

Let A be an uncountable union of open sets. I want to show it is a Borel set, so I must show that it is in every $\sigma$-algebra containing the open intervals.

Let X be a $\sigma$-algebra containing the open intervals. Then I claim ANY open set must be in X, so in particular A is in X.

The claim follows because (as you say) any open set can be expressed as a countable union of open intervals, and is therefore in X. We're done.

Thanks! I got the answer to my question -- the result doesn't follow directly from the definition.

Comment: An uncountable union of open sets is an open set. This is a topological fact that has nothing to do with $\sigma$-algebras. So no extra work is needed. If $A$ is an uncountable union of open sets, then it's an open set, hence it's a Borel set.

Comment: Oh, hmm. I would say that extra work has to be done to show that any open set can be expressed as a countable union of open intervals. No?

Comment: Yes, that's where the work is. The proof isn't too hard - see the link I gave in the first comment. It should also be in almost any elementary real analysis text.

Answer (score 0):

Every open Set in R is the countable union of open intervals of the form        (q-1/n,q+1/n) where q is rational and n is a positive interval .This show that every open set is a Borel set according to your definition .

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra containing all open intervals, then the Borel algebra $\mathcal{B}$ is defined by $$\mathcal{B}:=\langle \mathcal{O}\rangle=\bigcap_{I \in \mathcal{O}} I.$$ That is, $\mathcal{B}$ is the “smallest” $\sigma$-algebra containing the closed intervals.

Here $\langle  {\mathcal{O}}\rangle$ is the set generated by the elements $I \in \mathcal{O}$.