# Examples of writting an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ as a countable union of disjoint open sets.

Tags: real-analysis

I understand [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/318303/567288) of the theorem, but my problem is applying this to some open sets. For example, how would be the disjoint open sets in the countable union that cover, for instance, the open sets $\mathbb{R}$, $(0,1)$ and $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$ of $\mathbb{R}$ in the context of this proof? I'm having a really hard time visualizing them.
Thanks.

Comment: Note that sets of cardinality one or two are also countable

Comment: but then would't the union be uncountable?

Comment: Countable in this context means "finite or countably infinite." So (0,1) is already a finite union of open intervals.

Comment: Oh, yes, now I see. Ty. But what about $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is an open set so it covers itself with a single open set.

Comment: Oh, of course. I'm feeling very dumb right now. Thank you very much.

Comment: No worries, I've seen a lot of people get tripped up on this one.

Comment: If you write these comments as an answer I can give you the points