# Any open set $G\subset\mathbb{R}$ has the form $G=\sqcup_i (a_i,b_i)$.

Tags: real-analysis

In real analysis class, the professor used a basic property to give an easier definition of measurable function, it says:

Any open set $G\subset\mathbb{R}$ has the form $G=\sqcup_i (a_i,b_i)$.

It is an axiom? or how to prove it?

By the way, it seems I need some background knowledge of this kind of set properties. Are there some materials I can refer?

Comment: It can definitely be proved.

Comment: Can you give me some hints?

Comment: If you want to read up about it: This statement comes from topology and is valid because the open intervals form a [base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) of the natural topology.

Comment: @Xuchuang just take maximal intervals in $G$. $G$ is then the disjoint union of them

Comment: @mathworker21 Yes, this can be proved in this way, thank you.

Comment: @JoRa, thanks for your information.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318299/any-open-subset-of-bbb-r-is-a-at-most-countable-union-of-disjoint-open-interv This is a big list concerning the topic.

Answer (score 0):

The above-given form of open sets is not canonical, the assignment
of indices $i$ to the open component intervals is arbitrary. Let's write it in an equivalent but canonical way:

$\quad$ Every open set $\ G\subseteq\mathbb R\ $ is of the form
      $$ G\ =\ \bigcup \Gamma $$
where $\ \Gamma $ is a family of pairwise disjoint open intervals. Such family $\ \Gamma\ $ is unique and countable (possibly finite).

**Indeed**, define a binary relation in $\ G\ $ as follows:

$$ \forall{x,\ y\in G}\quad (\,x\equiv y\,\ \Leftrightarrow
 \,\ [\min(x\,\ y);\ \max(x\,\ y)]\ \subseteq G\,) $$

It's clear that

- relation $\ \equiv\ $ is an equivalence relation in $G$,
- every equivalence class of $\ \equiv\ $ is an open convex set,
- every non-empty open convex set $\ D\subseteq\mathbb R\ $ is
    an open interval, namely

$$ D\ =\ (\inf D;\sup D) $$

Family $\ \Gamma\ $ is countable because of every
open interval having a rational number as its point (obviously,
any two different equivalence classes do not share any rational number -- after all, different classes are disjoint).
.

*That's all.*

Comment: Very clear. Many thanks!

Comment: Xuchuang, thank you for good words. But, please, let me keep my notation which is mostly free of commas. I use it for years and it is accepted on the Internet almost always. It is my notation which is clearer than the standard commas which are but an eyesore. You can get used to this good thing fast. The commas are a relict of the pre-Chinese/Gutenberg times. Now we don't need them in print.

Comment: Of course $\ (a\ b):=\{x\in\mathbb R: a<x<b\}\ $ and $\ [a;b]:=\{x\in\mathbb R: a\le x\le b\}\ $ etc.

Comment: sure, if you like. I'm OK with that.