# $\mathbb{R}$ is union of countable collection of disjoint open intervals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I've found really good answers for the question from link below.

[Any open subset of $\Bbb R$ is a at most countable union of disjoint open intervals. [Collecting Proofs]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318299/any-open-subset-of-bbb-r-is-a-at-most-countable-union-of-disjoint-open-interv)

But I have a question about how $\mathbb{R}$, which is open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, can be expressed as union of countable collection of disjoint open intervals. In my intuition, it seems not possible.... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open intervals in $\Bbb R$ are allowed to extend to $\infty$, so $(-\infty,\infty)$ is one open interval that is all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Oh...so infinite end point is possible. Thank you!!

Comment: In one sense it is not an end point, because the interval is open.  The use of $\infty$ means there is no end point.

Comment: Oh that's right Thanks for correction