# Does the set of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ is countable?

Tags: measure-theory, cardinals, borel-sets, borel-measures

I want to prove that the cardinality of Borel $\sigma $ algebra is $\aleph$, using the next proposition:
If $ E \subset P(X) $ is infinite, and the cardinality of E is $\aleph $ , the $\sigma$ algebra generated by E is of cardinality $\aleph$.
Im pretty stuck with the step of proving that the generators of that $\sigma$ algebra, which are the open sets of Borel, is of the requested cardinality.
Here, I'm taking the standard topology on R, where $\aleph$ is the cardinality of continoum.

Comment: $\aleph$ does not refer to a single cardinal. Do you mean $\aleph_0$ instead? Also, open under what topology? The usual one?

Comment: @URL: $\aleph$ is sometimes used to denote the cardinality of the continuum. This goes back to Hasudorff.

Comment: When you write $\aleph$, I think you mean $\aleph_0$, but the are are uncountably many open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology.  All the sets $(0,x)$ where $x>0$ are open, so there are at least $\mathfrak{c}$ open sets.

Comment: @saulspatz: `\mathfrak c`. Also my comment. The Borel algebra is not countable, just to clarify.

Comment: Ron, I think you want $E\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$, not $E\in\mathcal P(X)$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes offcourse, edited.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks, on both counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is [a countable union of open intervals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318299/any-open-subset-of-bbb-r-is-a-countable-union-of-disjoint-open-intervals), so the open intervals generate the Borel sets.  There are $\aleph$ open intervals, so the theorem you quote completes the proof.