# How can the Cantor set be uncountable, yet its complement is the union of only countably many disjoint open intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, cantor-set

$C$ = Cantor set. $C$ is closed, so $C^c$ is the [countable union of disjoint open intervals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318299/any-open-subset-of-bbb-r-is-a-countable-union-of-disjoint-open-intervals). So let $$C^c = \bigcup\limits_{\substack{i~\in~\mathbb{N} \\}} A_i $$

where $A_i$ are disjoint open intervals.

For each $i \in \mathbb{N},\ A_i\ $ differs from a closed set by just two points, namely the endpoints of the interval $A_i.$ For each $i \in \mathbb{N},\ $ let

$$ B_i = \{x_{i1}, x_{i2} \} = \{ \text{ the two endpoints of } A_i \}. $$

Then $\left|\bigcup\limits_{\substack{i~\in~\mathbb{N} \\}} B_i\right| \leq 2 \left|\mathbb{N}\right| $ is countable. However, $\bigcup\limits_{\substack{i~\in~\mathbb{N} \\}} B_i$ is surely the Cantor set, which is uncountable.

Something is incorrect in all of this, but what?

Comment: An amusing illustration of the general principle "if you want to find the error, look for words like _clearly_, _surely_, etc."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of points in the Cantor set other than the end points of the intervals $A_i$. Infinite sums of the type $\sum \frac {a_i} {3^{i}}$  ($a_i \in \{0,2\}$) are in $C$ and they are not end points  unless the sum reduces to a finite sum.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that.

Comment: Ah wikipedia says ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Composition ): "It may appear that only the endpoints of the construction segments are left, but that is not the case either. The number $\frac{1}{4}$, for example, has the unique ternary form $0.020202... $. It is in the bottom third, and the top third of that third, and the bottom third of that top third, and so on. Since it is never in one of the middle segments, it is never removed. Yet it is also not an endpoint of any middle segment, because it is not a multiple of any power of $\frac{1}{3}.$"