# Is axiom of choice required to throw away repeated intervals in a constructive argument?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, set-theory, real-numbers, axiom-of-choice

I am looking at this answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318299/any-open-subset-of-bbb-r-is-a-countable-union-of-disjoint-open-intervals):

> Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be open and let $x \in U$. Either $x$ is rational or irrational. If $x$ is rational, define
> \begin{align}I_x = \bigcup\limits_{\substack{I\text{ an open interval} \\ x~\in~I~\subseteq~U}} I,\end{align}
> which, as a union of non-disjoint open intervals (each $I$ contains $x$),  is an open interval subset to $U$. If $x$ is irrational, by openness of $U$ there is $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $(x - \varepsilon, x + \varepsilon) \subseteq U$, and there exists rational $y \in (x - \varepsilon, x + \varepsilon) \subseteq I_y$ (by the definition of $I_y$). Hence $x \in I_y$. So any $x \in U$ is in $I_q$ for some $q \in U \cap \mathbb{Q}$, and so
> \begin{align}U \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{q~\in~U \cap~\mathbb{Q}} I_q.\end{align}
> But $I_q \subseteq U$ for each $q \in U \cap \mathbb{Q}$; thus
> \begin{align}U = \bigcup\limits_{q~\in~U \cap~\mathbb{Q}} I_q, \end{align}
> which is a countable union of open intervals.

In particular, I am reading his comments that

> That it is a disjoint union follows from the definition of $I_q$: if $x\in I_p\cap I_q$, then $I_p\cup I_q\subseteq I_p \cap I_q$. Hence if $I_q\neq  I_p$, $I_p\cap I_q=\emptyset$. Strictly speaking one should throw away all repeated $I_q$
> s, and one can definitely do this without destroying the countability of the union.

How does one throw away all the repeated $I_q$s here? Is axiom of choice required?

Comment: It seems to me that the index set is still $\Bbb Q$, which is well-orderable. So the answer is no. More generally, let $X$ be a well-orderable set and let $f:X\to Y$ be a function. For any well-order $(X,\le)$, the set $S=\{x\in X\,:\, x=\min_\le\{u\in X\,:\, f(u)=f(x)\}\}$ satisfies the property of $\left.f\right\rvert_S$ being a bijection onto the image of $f$.

Comment: Note that this argument is not “constructive” in the generally used sense, since we cannot constructively decide whether a real number is rational or irrational.

Comment: Another way of handling this without the axiom of choice: Just define the set of intervals $\mathscr I = \{ I_p : p\in \Bbb Q\}$. Since it is the codomain of the surjective function $\Bbb Q \to \mathscr I : p \mapsto I_p$ which has a countable domain, $\scr I$ is countable. And any particular interval in $\scr I$ is contained in it only once. An element is either in a set, or not in a set. The set does not contain it multiple times.