# A function which conserves null-sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $F: \Bbb{R} \hookrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ a continuous map that satisfies $\forall x < y : f(x) < f(y)$ and \begin{equation} \tag{I} \label{I} \lambda(A) = 0 \rightarrow \lambda(F(A))=0 \end{equation}
> where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.
> If $G(x)=x+F(x)$, then also $G$ satisfies \ref{I}.

I am getting stuck with this. If I am not wrong, it can be proved using the definition. I mean, given $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\{I_k=(a_k, b_k)\}_{k\in \Bbb{N}} : A \subseteq \bigcup_{k\in \Bbb{N}} I_k \land \sum_{k\in \Bbb{N}} l(I_k) < \varepsilon$. The problem is that I do not know how to use the increasity of $F$ to relate this with a cover for $F(A)$ and then for $G(A)$.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $I=(a,b)$ is an interval, then
$$\lambda(G(I))=(b+F(b))-(a+F(a))=(b-a)+(F(b)-F(a))=\lambda(I)+\lambda(F(I)).$$

By considering disjoint unions of open intervals, we can establish the same result for open sets: $$\lambda(G(U))=\lambda(U)+\lambda(F(U)).$$

Suppose that $\epsilon>0$ and $\lambda(A)=0$.  Then we can find an open set $U\supseteq A$ with $\lambda(U)<\epsilon/2$  Further, since $\lambda(F(A))=0$, we can find an open set $V\supseteq F(A)$ such $\lambda(V)<\epsilon/2$.  Since $F$ is continuous, $F^{-1}(V)$ is open, hence $F^{-1}(V)\cap U$ is too, and

$$\lambda(G(F^{-1}(V)\cap U))=\lambda(F(F^{-1}(V)\cap U))+\lambda(F^{-1}(V)\cap U)\leq \lambda(V)+\lambda(U)=\epsilon.$$

Comment: I don't think it's true that any open set is a *disjoint* union of open intervals. But proving this for disjoint open intervals is definitely enough. You can then consider compact subsets and use inner regularity. It's definitely far cleaner than my proof.

Comment: @DavidGao https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318299/any-open-subset-of-bbb-r-is-a-countable-union-of-disjoint-open-intervals

Comment: I didn't know about this fact. This is interesting - Thanks for sharing! Everything seems to work out fine in your proof then.

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be compact and null. We first show that $\lambda(G(A)) = 0$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, as $A$ is null, there exists open intervals $\{I_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ s.t. $A \subseteq \cup_k I_k$ and $\sum_k l(I_k) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. As $A$ is compact, there is a finite subcover, i.e., there exists finitely many open intervals $\{I_j\}_{j = 1}^n$ with $A \subseteq \cup_{j = 1}^n I_j$ and $\sum_{j = 1}^n l(I_j) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. By adjoining two open intervals together if they intersect, we may assume $I_j$ are disjoint. We may further assume $I_j$ are ordered in accordance with the usual order on the real line. Let $I_j = (a_j, b_j)$. As $F$ is strictly increasing, we have $F(\cup_{j = 1}^n I_j) = \cup_{j = 1}^n (F(a_j), F(b_j))$. We observe that these intervals are disjoint and also ordered in accordance with the usual order on the real line.

Now, as $F$ is continuous, $F(A)$ is compact. Per our assumptions, $F(A)$ is also null. So by the same argument we see that there exists finitely many disjoint open intervals $\{L_k\}_{k = 1}^m$ with $F(A) \subseteq \cup_{k = 1}^m L_k$ and $\sum_{k = 1}^m l(L_k) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Furthermore, we shall assume $L_k$ are ordered in accordance with the usual order on the real line. Since $A \subseteq \cup_{j = 1}^n I_j$ and $F(\cup_{j = 1}^n I_j) = \cup_{j = 1}^n (F(a_j), F(b_j))$, we also have $F(A) \subseteq \cup_{j = 1}^n (F(a_j), F(b_j))$. We may delete all $j$ such that $(F(a_j), F(b_j))$ does not intersect any $L_k$. Indeed, if $x \in I_j$ for some $j$ s.t. $(F(a_j), F(b_j))$ does not intersect any $L_k$, then $F(x) \in (F(a_j), F(b_j)) \notin \cup_k L_k \supseteq A$, so $F(x) \notin F(A)$ and $x \notin A$. Therefore, deleting all such $j$ does not affect the covering of $A$. We may therefore assume WLOG that every $(F(a_j), F(b_j))$ intersects some $L_k$.

Now, both $\{L_k\}_{k = 1}^m$ and $\{(F(a_j), F(b_j))\}_{j = 1}^n$ are disjoint, ordered collections of open intervals, so for each $j$ there exists $k^1_j, k^2_j \in \{1, \cdots, m\}$ s.t. $(F(a_j), F(b_j))$ intersects $L_k$ iff $k^1_j \leq k \leq k^2_j$ and furthermore we have $k^1_1 \leq k^2_1 \leq k^1_2 \leq k^2_2 \leq \cdots \leq k^1_n \leq k^2_n$. Let $L'_{jk} = (F(a_j), F(b_j)) \cap L_k$ when $k^1_j \leq k \leq k^2_j$. Then $F(A) \subseteq \cup_{j = 1}^n \cup_{k = k^1_j}^{k^2_j} L'_{jk}$. $L'_{jk}$ are disjoint nonempty open intervals which, when ordered lexicographically in $j$ then $k$, are ordered in accordance with the usual order on the real line. As such, for each $j$ there exists $a_j \leq c^1_{j, k^1_j} < c^2_{j, k^1_j} \leq c^1_{j, k^1_j + 1} < c^2_{j, k^1_j + 1} \leq \cdots \leq c^1_{jk^2_j} < c^2_{jk^2_j}$ s.t. $F(c^1_{j, k})$ (resp., $F(c^2_{j, k})$) is the left (resp., right) endpoint of $L'_{jk}$ for all $k^1_j \leq k \leq k^2_j$. Then, for any $x \in A \cap I_j$, there must exists a unique $k^1_j \leq k \leq k^2_j$ s.t. $x \in (c^1_{j, k}, c^2_{j, k})$. So $G(x) = x + F(x) \in (c^1_{j, k} + F(c^1_{j, k}), c^2_{j, k} + F(c^2_{j, k}))$. Hence,

$$G(A) \subseteq \cup_{j = 1}^n \cup_{k = k^1_j}^{k^2_j} (c^1_{j, k} + F(c^1_{j, k}), c^2_{j, k} + F(c^2_{j, k}))$$

So $\lambda(G(A)) \leq \sum_{j = 1}^n \sum_{k = k^1_j}^{k^2_j} [(c^2_{j, k} - c^1_{j, k}) + (F(c^2_{j, k}) - F(c^1_{j, k}))]$. We have,

$$\sum_{j = 1}^n \sum_{k = k^1_j}^{k^2_j} (c^2_{j, k} - c^1_{j, k}) \leq \sum_{j = 1}^n l(I_j) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

And,

$$\sum_{j = 1}^n \sum_{k = k^1_j}^{k^2_j} (F(c^2_{j, k}) - F(c^1_{j, k})) = \sum_{j = 1}^n \sum_{k = k^1_j}^{k^2_j} l(L'_{jk}) \leq \sum_{k = 1}^m l(L_k) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Thus, $\lambda(G(A)) \leq \epsilon$. As $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, this shows $\lambda(G(A)) = 0$ whenever $A$ is compact and null.

The general case follows from inner regularity. Indeed, if $A$ is null, to show $G(A)$ is null, it suffices to show all compact subsets $K \subseteq G(A)$ is null. $G$ is strictly increasing, continuous, and clearly surjective, so it admits a continuous inverse $G^{-1}$. Thus, $G^{-1}(K)$ is a compact subset of $A$, whence null. So $K = G(G^{-1}(K))$ is null as well.