# Prove that $G$ is an open interval for two-valued continuous function $f$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

> Suppose $G\subset \mathbb R$ is a non-empty open set such that the function $f:G \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ is a two-valued function and is continuous. Show that any two-valued function on $G$ is a constant *if and only if* the set $G$ is an open interval.

I am concerning about the construction of open set for set $G$ and have no idea to start off with.

Comment: Do you know about this fact? If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous and $X$ is connected, then $f(X)$ is connected

Comment: I don't know this fact, though.

Comment: So I have to prove the subset $G$ is connected in order to proceed?

Comment: You can also use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: I would like to listen to the idea that IVT works in the proof here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theorem**: A metric space $X$ is connected if and only if any continuous function $f:X\to \{0,1\}$ is constant.

**Proof**:Suppose $X$ is connected and $f:X\to \{0,1\}$ is continuous. If $f$ is not a constant function, then $f$ is onto. Let $A=f^{-1}(0)$ and $B=f^{-1}(1)$. Then $A\cup B=X$,and $A,B\neq \emptyset$. Also note that both are proper subsets of $X$ and are open and  closed in $X$, a contradiction.

Suppose $X$ is not connected. Let $A$ and $B$ be the disconnection. Then define $f:X\to \{0,1\}$ such that  $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0, &\text{if $x\in A$}\\
1,&\text{if $x\in B$}
\end{cases}$$

$f$ is a non-constant continuous function(verify).

Another useful theorem is

> A subset  $I$ of $\Bbb{R}$ is connected if and only if $I$ is an
>   interval.

You can find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239063/intervals-are-connected-and-the-only-connected-sets-in-mathbbr).

I hope now you can complete your answer on your own.

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ is an open interval then IVP tells you that if $f$ if takes both the values $0$ and $1$ then it must take all values in between. This proves one way.

For the other way use the fact any open set is a disjoint union of open intervals. If $G$ is a union of two or mote intervals define $f$ to be $1$ on one of them and $0$ on all the others. You will get a continuous function taking both the values $0$ and $1$ (and no other value).