# Connected Properties of an Interval Set

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

Can an interval on the real line, $(a,b)\subset \mathbb R$ be connected if its **inf** and **sup** are not part of the interval? Obviously if the **inf** and **sup** of the interval are not in the interval it cannot be a closed interval.

Comment: what about the interval $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Are there intervals that are not connected? (no) What is an "interval set" – just an interval? I almost don't understand the question.

Comment: Yes, I mean the set is simply just an interval

Comment: If the sup and inf of an interval are not included in the interval. Is the interval still connected?

Comment: Hi are you still there Brian? I want to know if the inf and sup of an interval are not part of the interval. Is the interval still connected?

Answer (score 0):

$(1,2)$ is connected

$\sup(1,2) \notin (1,2)$

$\inf(1,2) \notin (1,2)$

---

Further reading:

[Intervals are connected and the only connected sets in $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239063/intervals-are-connected-and-the-only-connected-sets-in-mathbbr)

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subset_of_Real_Numbers_is_Interval_iff_Connected

[Set $A$ interval in $\mathbb{R}\implies$ connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113007/set-a-interval-in-mathbbr-implies-connected)